Why doesn't the the new remote environment show up as Conda and update when new packages are installed
I tried closing and reopening VS Code, but it didn't work. I also tried adding Jupyter to my Python Notebook on my school's remote Almalinux server, but there was no change.  Since I am running Windows 11 and my remote is Linux, I can't fill in the path to a remote Conda.exe.


When I moved to the new environment, changing the remote Python Path was just one of two steps. The other step was changing the Conda to the new environment on the upper right.
 
[![Place to change the path to the current Conda][1]][1]

